# HasManyThrough relationship in Laravel with non-standard foreign keys

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, eloquent

In my Laravel app I have the following schema (and corresponding models):

```
clients
    id - integer (primary)
    name - string

accounts
    id - integer (primary)
    account_id - string (unique)
    client_id - integer (foreign, references id on clients)
    name - string

contracts
    id - integer (primary)
    account_id - string (foreign, references account_id on accounts)
    title - string
```

I want a `hasManyThrough` relationship so I can get all the contracts for a given Client, so I define the relationship in my `Client` model:

```
public function contracts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Contract', 'Account', 'client_id', 'account_id');
}
```

This doesn't work. The reason being that the relationship between `Contract` and `Account` is joined by `contracts.account_id = account.account_id` (**not** `contracts.account_id = account.id`).

This is an unconventional relationship by is necessary for the structure of the application. However there seems to not be a way to define the joined key on the intermediate model.

Is there a way to get around this or do I need to construct the query myself?

**Update**

Currently, the way I'm working around this is to use a query scope. On my `Contract` model I add the following:

```
public function scopeForClient($query, Client $client)
{
    return $query->whereIn('account_id', $client->accounts->lists('account_id'));
}
```

This allows me to do `Contract::forClient($client);` which is almost as elegant but probably is slightly worse performance due to eager loading the accounts as well as the lists operation.

Having the relationship work properly would still be preferable.

Comment: I dont see the foreign key at contracts referencing a string value in accounts. It should by all means refer to the id of accounts. Then you can get any data you want by properly writing the query.

Comment: As explained, the schema is such that `contracts.account_id` references `accounts.account_id` (not `accounts.id`). The issue is telling this to the `hasManyThrough()` method. The other `hasMany()` and `belongsTo()` methods support this.

Comment: What is the business logic? Each client can have several accounts and each account has one contract? or a client has only one acount and that account has many contracts?

Comment: No, the schema should make this obvious. Client has many Accounts; Accounts has many Contracts

Comment: And what about creating instead a table with a composite primary key? like accounts and contracts and client as a foreign key